# How does multiple recursive calls inside a loop unfolds?

Tags: c++, recursion

I am unable to trace recursion for the following piece of code:

```
void func(int n)
{
    if(n<=1)
       return;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        func(n-1);
        cout << n;
        func(n-1);
    }
}
```

How does the **recursion tree** look like and how the function calls will be made for the given code if we call **func(3)**?

Comment: well, run it and see it directly... :)

Comment: I did but i couldn't trace the code manually! @ewcz

Comment: @KenilPatel That's what your debugger is for! Anyone can tap a key and watch some red dots fly about the screen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just drew a partial trace tree, the nodes will be executed as the red numbers

[image: The trace tree]

The output is `223222232222322`

Comment: How come the cout <<3 is making call to f(2) and f(2)??
I am  not getting it!

Comment: The diagram shows the sequence of execution of statements, it is not actually the function calling nodes.